# Fantasy manhua involving two siblings; the brother has a system thingy that lets him roll or gacha while the sister can control souls of the dead

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

So I've been reading this manhua a long time ago but decided to stop because I caught up with the chapter. But now I decided to reread it again but I forgot the title of that manhua.

The manhua is about two siblings (the older one is a boy while the younger one is a girl) and the boy has a low rank but one time he was hit by a truck. After he woke up, he has this like system thingy and it lets him roll (or gacha and I remember that he always get stinky tofu). Fast forward, the girl also awakened and she can control souls of the dead.

That's all I can remember lol, please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[Spare Me, Great Lord!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/spare-me-great-lord)***...?

> As the superpower awoke, everyone was sparing no effort to cultivate. Lu Shu was the only one who could get stronger by collecting others’ negative feelings and calling people names! All he ever wanted was to protect his little sister, but no one could resist the trend of the world...Well, he'd just do what he had to do and thus become the strongest! Are you ready to welcome the "Super Demon" Lu Shu?
>
> [image: Promotional art for "Spare Me, Great Lord!."]

The protagonist is a teenaged boy named Lu Shu. He has a younger sister named Lu Xiaoyu (they aren't blood related, but grew up together as orphans). The story is set in a modern world where some people have super powers and are known as Awakened.

In the first chapter, Shu is hit by a truck and seemingly killed. He then wakes up and gets to his feet, covered in blood, and then goes home and showers. While in the shower, some menu screens pop up in front of him that allow him to buy items or win them by spinning a lottery wheel. He gains points for his system from the negative feelings of people around him.

In chapter 11, he spins his lottery wheel and wins some stinky tofu. He and Xiaoyu eat some, and in later chapters, he produces more of it and sells it to make money.

In chapter 13, he helps Xiaoyu become Awakened with a glowing sheet of paper that he won from his lottery wheel (he referred to it as a cultivation trick).

In chapter 28, Xiaoyu uses her powers to control the spirit of a man who'd recently died.

You can read the full manhua at [WebNovel](https://www.webnovel.com/comic/spare-me-great-lord!_16541051906427701###).